# Ansible nested loop with dynamic group name

Tags: ansible

My vars file :

```
applications:
  - name: server_1
    deploy: True
    branch: master
    group: frontend
  - name: server_2
    deploy: True
    branch: master
    group: backend
```

My task is

```
- name: deploy boxer
  command: "curl http://example.com?hosts={{item.1}}"
  with_subelements:
    - applications
    - "{{ groups[group] }}" # This is not working.
```

inventory.yml

```
[frontend]
host1.example.com
host2.example.com

[backend]
host11.example.com
host12.example.com
```

I want to iterate through applications, and loop through each hosts in a group (only one host at a time) to pass it to curl command.

I want this at the end.

```
curl http://example.com?hosts=host1.example.com
curl http://example.com?hosts=host2.example.com
curl http://example.com?hosts=host11.example.com
curl http://example.com?hosts=host12.example.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to use [with_nested](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_loops.html#nested-loops)?

```
 with_nested:
   - "{{ applications }}"
   - "{{ groups }}"
 when: item.0.group == item.1
```

Comment: Am gettin this error.

FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "ERROR! The conditional check 'item.0.group == item.1' failed. The error was: ERROR! error while evaluating conditional (item.0.group == item.1): ERROR! 'None' has no attribute 'group'\n\n

Comment: Oh yes, `with_nested` was it actually.

Comment: item.1 is not giving me the host name. I want to loop through all the host names.